# Docker postgress database image rake db:migrate disk full error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

Getting not enough disk space error on docker machine rails migration using `docker-compose run web bundle exec rake db:migrate` even with plenty of space on disk

Comment: Please adjust your question to [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sounds fairly self-explanatory. Do you have enough disk space left on your host?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have dangling images. You can remove these using simply:

```
docker image prune
```

It will not delete volumes, databases, etc...

Answer (score 0):

The docker machine was full, so you can free up space on your local hard drive as well as follow these commands:

Free up the space by removing all unused containers, networks, images (both dangling and unreferenced), and optionally, volumes.

`docker system prune -a`

`docker volume prune`

Note that this will delete the database and you must perform

`docker-compose up`

And then recreate the database and fill it again.